Render Error after upgrade React Native 68 -> 73 (Drawer)
I have done a fair amount of work upgrading libraries and code while trying to switch to RN 0.73.9 but I cannot come over this issue:
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'focusedRoute.key')

This error is located at:
    in DrawerItemList (created by DrawerContent)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView
    in DrawerContentScrollView (created by DrawerContent)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DrawerContent)
    in DrawerContent (created by Drawer)
....

This is the problem in component source code, not in mine, right?
There are other answers which say "all navigation libs must be roughly on same version" and I think they are:
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "6.7.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.0",

I was able to localize the troubling place a bit: the original code is below which fails. If I remove second branch (Drawer.Screen) the app starts (but of course does not show the drawer).
      <RootStack.Navigator >
        {showSplash == true ? <RootStack.Screen name="Loading" component={SplashScreen} /> : <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={MainDrawer} />}
      </RootStack.Navigator>

So I am stuck! Any ideas where to look?
